# Facebook apps: 'How to ad app page description for like button

Tags: facebook-like

I have a facebook app with a like button embedded in it. Now when a user clicks 'like', 
it displays on their timeline right. The problem is that only my app's Title and image shows up. how do I add/show a description as well? Maybe an attribute for the like button?
My like button  below:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=353195451398908&amp;xfbml=1">  
</script><fb:like href="http://apps.facebook.com/e-phoneapp" layout="button_count" 
width="90" height="24px" show_faces="false" action="like" font="lucida grande"></fb:like>
```

Thanks